# How do I export a random sample of a csv in GCS to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm working with a large CSV (400M+ lines) located in a GCS bucket. I need to get a random sample of this csv and export it to BigQuery for a preliminary exploration. I've looked all the over the web and I just can't seem to find anything that addresses this question.

Is this possible and how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can query your csv file [directly from BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive) using external tables.

Try it with [TABLESAMPLE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-sampling) clause:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (10 PERCENT)
```

Comment: This only works if the table is already in bigquery. I want to export a sample from the bucket to bigquery. For example, instead of exporting all 400M lines to bigquery, I want to export 1000 random lines

Comment: External tables are not stored in BigQuery. They allow to query data stored in CloudStorage [without copying data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#overview).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [external table from GCS (to read directly from GCS)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#creating_and_querying_a_permanent_external_table) and then do something like that

```
SELECT * FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<externalTableFromGCS>` 
WHERE CAST(10*RAND() AS INT64) = 0
```

The result of the select can be stored in [GCS with an export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement) or stored in a table with an `insert select`

Keep in mind that you need to fully load the file (and thus to pay for the full file size) and then query a subset of the file. You can't load only 10% of the volume in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to load sample records from GCS to BigQuery, But we can achieve it in different way, In GCS we have option to download only specific chunk of file, so following simple python code can load sample records to BQ from large big GCS file

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery

gcs_client = storage.Client()
bq_client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(source_format='CSV', autodetect=True, max_bad_records=1)

bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket("your-bucket")
blob = storage.Blob('gcs_path/file.csv', bucket)
    
with open('local_file.csv', 'wb') as f:    # downloading sample file
    gcs_client.download_blob_to_file(blob, f, start=0, end=2000)

with open('local_file.csv', "rb") as source_file:   # uploading to BQ
    job = bq_client.load_table_from_file(source_file, 'your-proj.dataset.table_id', job_config=job_config)

job.result() # Wait for loading
```

In above code, it will download 2 kb of data from your huge GCS file, But
last row in the downloaded csv file may incomplete since we cannot define the bytes for each rows. Here the trickier part is **"max_bad_records=1"** in bq job config so it will ignore the uncompleted last row.